# What is difference between the getIdToken and getAppCheckToken?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-app-check

Currently firebase has introduce the App Check. To protect the non firebase backend firebase has introduce getAppCheckToken. Previously we are using the getIdToken to verify the user.

```
 FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser.getIdToken(true).addOnSuccessListener {
    Log.d("tag",it.token) // token #1
}

FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance()
        .getAppCheckToken(false)
        .addOnSuccessListener { tokenResponse ->
    Log.d("tag",tokenResponse) // token #1
}
```

What's difference between both this two token. How getAppCheckToken can improve the security of the non firebase backend.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the difference between **getIdToken** and **getAppCheckToken** is:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser.getIdToken(true){}
```

> Fetches a Firebase Auth ID Token for the user; useful when authenticating against your own backend, if forceRefresh == true, thrown if the current user's account has been disabled, deleted, or its credentials are no longer valid.

```
FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance().getAppCheckToken(true){}
```

> Requests a Firebase App Check token. This method should be used ONLY if you need to authorize requests to a non-Firebase backend. Requests to Firebase backends are authorized automatically if configured.